# SQL 2016 SSRS Web Service URL not opening

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am totally new to SSRS.

I can access and open SQL Server Report Manager URL page but can not access Report server URL for SQL Server 2016. When I tried to open Report Server URL in chrome, its showing below user

> This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Installed version is 13.0.5081.1 SQL Server 2016 SSRS.

Comment: Did you grant access rights to the user as part of the setup/config/installation?

Comment: Yes, given rights to user.